# Remove slash in htaccess ReWrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a ReWrite rule that has 2 parameters, but the `nav` parameter shows a `/` before because of the URL.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)?$ index.php?pagename=$1&nav=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Is there a way I can remove the slash in the htaccess code?

Comment: that's a bit unclear. What's the input URL you are hitting, what is the output you are getting and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Put The slash `/` out of capturing group `^([^/]+)(/[a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)?$` like this `^([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)?$` .

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([\w/-]+))?$ index.php?pagename=$1&nav=$2 [L,QSA]
```

- `(?:...)?` is an optional non-capture group
- `([\w/-]+)` inside this non-capture group will populate 2nd capture group